# Custom outputPath for sbt-assembly

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have multi-project `Build.scala`. Is there a way to place all jars generated by sbt-assembly in the root target directory?

For example, consider the following:

```
lazy val root = Project("root", file(".")).aggregate(hello)

lazy val hello = Project(id = "hello", base = file("hello"))
   .settings(assemblySettings: _*)
```

As is, if I run `sbt assembly`, `hello.jar` would be placed in `hello/target/<scala-version>/`. Is possible instead to place it in `/target/<scala-version>/`?

I know it's possible to specify the outputPath I want by adding the following setting:

```
target in assembly := file("target/scala-2.11/")
```

Is there any way to make this more generic? For example, so it is not necessary to manually specify the scala version?

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 10):

```
assemblyOutputPath in assembly := file("yourpath")
```

Comment: I had an issue with path here on mac. So I used `baseDirectory.value` and from there I navigated to the required path which is relative. Otherwise it takes the path from home which might not be what you need.

Comment: Is there anyway I can specify from the command line?? e.g. `sbt assembly --assemblyOutputPath=Yourpath"`??

Comment: assemblyOutputPath is actually less generic than target. It's literally target + assemblyJarName. How is this upvoted?

Answer (score 2):

A small improvement on this answer. If you need to retain the file name that is generated by assembly plugin do it as below:

```
assembly / assemblyOutputPath := file(s"/path/to/jar/${(assembly/assemblyJarName).value}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `assemblyOutputPath` via cmd:

```
sbt 'set assemblyOutputPath in assembly := new File("/path/to/package.jar")' assembly
```

In case you need to set multiple options - just use spaces:

```
sbt 'set test in assembly := {}' 'set assemblyOutputPath in assembly := new File("/path/to/package.jar")' assembly
```